# Which kinds of associations do classes have in a system? How to best represent them in UML?

Tags: c#, java, oop, uml

This post is actually divided in two questions:

### Which kinds of associations classes/interfaces usually have?

I'd say there are at least 3 kinds of dependencies:

- Inheritance : I think we all know this one)
- Dependency : with this I mean that if `class A` depends on `class B`, I can only instantiate `class A` if I pass it `class B` as constructor argument. Is this correct?
- Uses : `class A` uses `class B` if there is any kind of reference of `class B` in the code of `class A` that is neither inheritance of dependency.

Are these the only kind of associations between classes? Are my interpretations of what they mean correct?

### Which kind of dependencies are of our interest to show on UML diagrams (mostly class/package diagrams)?

Up until now, I've mostly only put in class diagrams arrows depicting dependencies associations. But now that I think of it, most of the time I look at class diagrams, I'll find something along the lines of

[image]

where only `Inherits` and `Uses` associations are shown. But those `Uses` in the class diagram aren't really the same kind of `Uses` I've defined above. They are just a way of telling you there's a getter on a class of a type that's not a primitive.

I guess that if I had to look to some system's documentation I'd like to know how different classes in the system depend on each other. I'd definetely like to have some sort of `Dependency Graph` to look at.

Would it better to restrict class diagrams to `Inherits/Uses` associations and then have other diagram/graph that shows `Depends/Uses` associations?

How do you prefer it, and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should stop talking about inheritance, depends and uses relationships as "associations".  The word "Association" has a particular meaning in UML; see below.

Of the three relationships you mentioned, it is conventional to only show the inheritance (technically Generalization) relationships in a class diagram.  They are represented using solid lines with open triangle arrowheads.

If you wanted to show depends / uses relationships between classes, you should use the UML Dependency notation; i.e. a dashed line with a "vee" arrowhead.

The other kind of relationship that is commonly depicted in an class diagram is an Association; i.e. information-carrying relationships between instances of classes, that are typically represented using (for example) pointers, or database foreign keys / indexes.

I guess it is a matter of personal preference, but I wouldn't want to see depends/uses relationships on an object diagram.  It is difficult enough to layout the Generalization and Association lines.  Other lines are simply going to make the diagram too "busy".

The UML User Guide says:

> *"Remember that it is both undesirable and unnecessary to model all relationships among a set of abstractions in a single diagram or view.  Rather, build up your system's relationships by considering different views on the system.  Highlight interesting sets of relationships in individual diagrams."*

Comment: +1 for Associations.  If purpose of the diagram is to understand the problem domain then Associations are the "secret sauce".  Particularly if you use Verb phrases to name them.  Dependency, Uses etc. are more useful when looking at a body of code and trying to understand its structure.

Comment: Are you talking about Object diagrams or Class Diagrams? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram

Comment: Class Diagrams (although often these are confusingly termed "Object Models").